# Vim for python and R scripting (in Screen or not)

Tags: python, r, vim, terminal, screen

I've been trying to find this information online but I'm not getting the answer.

I've used `RStudio` and `Geany` for editing files before. Now I'm trying to use **ViM** to edit **python** and **R** files (I know there's `RPy`, but nothing to do with my problem).

I would like to know how can I have 3 terminals (could also be vim buffers, or screen windows) with one running **ViM** and the others running **R** and **Python**. When I execute a Python script, the terminal (window or buffer) with python shows the output. The same when I run R scripts.

I would appreciate insight on this as this is something that's keeping me from using ViM regularly. I would also consider a solution with `terminator` terminal multiplexer or `guake` terminal. Any information about sending code for scripting from one instance to another is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for a way to have a REPL inside Vim? If so, Vim wasn't really designed with that in mind, though there are some plugins that try. [Conque](https://code.google.com/p/conque/) is an example.

Some things I use to have a quicker code/run/test iteration with Python:

- IPython's `%edit` feature, which starts editing a script with `$EDITOR` and will run the script after you exit.
- [vim-ipython](https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython) which can send/execute/recieve code via an IPython interpreter.
- [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) which allows you to have multiple shells side by side, but with little interaction between them.

Comment: Thanks!, Conque is interesting and IPython's `edit` sounds even better. i even learn what REPL meant!, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Vim-slime is a general-purpose solution to this I'm pretty happy about, it will send blocks of code to any tmux pane, meaning it works for any language.

https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements for online information may not have been spelled out in enough detail, since I seem to find a wealth of information on using ViM as an IDE for both R and Python:

R:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-with-vim/

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2628

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1048

Python:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/Vim

http://blog.dispatched.ch/2009/05/24/vim-as-python-ide/

http://dancingpenguinsoflight.com/2009/02/python-and-vim-make-your-own-ide/

Comment: I appreciate your answer and the information. I had seen those pages and they all show workarounds for my problem. But they don't show how to direct the output to a particular existing window/buffer/terminal but will create their own.

Comment: I would say that this post comes pretty close to a [LMGTFY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links). OP was at pains to say they'd looked online so you can assume it'd been Googled.

Comment: I don't agree that I was showing disrespect for the poster in the manner deprecated by the responders to that Meta-posting. If you disagree and think this posting should be held up to public scrutiny, then feel free to link to my answer in a Meta-posting. (I do admit that I probably didn't understand the request.)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [vim-ipython](https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython), a plug-in for Vim.

You need to download the source (linked above), and run the Vim command `:source path/to/file/ipy.vim`.

Start by running a new IPython session (e.g. using `IPython qtconsole` or `IPython notebook`) and then type `:IPython` into Vim. Your Vim is now connected to the IPython instance you just opened.

You can press <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the whole python script in your Vim, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to run the current line. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> will also run whatever is selected if you're in visual (i.e. 'select') mode.